# kill my application process after the creation of backgroundservice

Tags: android, android-intent

**i want to know please : if it possible to kill my application process after the creation of my service. which does not require the process to be in running mode to make my application light in memory  ?**

Answer (score 1):

By default your [Service](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html) will run in same process as UI of your application, so it's not a good idea to kill main process of the app if Service is not moved to separate process.

If you really want to run Service in separate process, I'd suggest to don't try to kill main process of the application, if Android will decide to kill it -> it'll do it himself.

If device will run out of memory -> Android will unload your Activities (with saving state, of course), also Android can shutdown non-major services (see Foreground Service).

Comment: ok is it possible to finish the main activity since the service has been created and there's no need that the  main activity keep running anymore

Comment: Yes, you can call `finish()` on it or let user leave it.